# why does the onclick behave differently after page reload

Tags: javascript, local-storage, reload, shopping-cart, createelement

i have a shopping cart that works. it adds items and increases quantity, and removes them when remove is pressed. i have made it so that the data is stored in local storage, so that if the page reloads the shopping cart is repopulated. this works, but, after i reload the page the cart populates correctly, and when i press the remove button, the wrong item removes, and this causes the code to crash if i try and remove another item. i cannot figure out what is wrong. its uses the same logic.

the additem() function populates the cart manually

and the onload() basically repeats the process of additem() from the data stored in the session.
the uploadprice() updates the cart total
and the updatestorage() function updates the string in the local storage

\\

```
function updatestorage(name,cost,code,operator){


if (operator === 'add'){


        if(localStorage.getItem("stringitem") === null || localStorage.getItem("stringitem") === ''){            //sets the first item in the string of items to localstorage

            let stringofitems = '1,' + name + ',' + cost + ',' + code + ',1';
            localStorage.setItem("stringitem",stringofitems);
            
        }else{

            let stringofitems = localStorage.getItem("stringitem");

            let arr = stringofitems.split(",");

            let count = (arr.length / 5 );

            let updated = 0;

            for(x = 1; x < arr.length; x = x + 5){

                if (arr[x] === name){
                    arr[x-1] = parseInt(arr[x-1]) + parseInt(1);
                    updated = 1;
                    let newstring = arr.join();
                  
                    localStorage.setItem("stringitem",newstring);
                }

            }
            if(updated == 0){
                count = parseInt(count) + parseInt(1);
                let newstringofitems = stringofitems + ',1,' + name + ',' + cost + ',' + code + ','  + count;
                localStorage.setItem("stringitem",newstringofitems);
            }
        }
    }
    if (operator === 'sub'){

        let stringofitems = localStorage.getItem("stringitem");

        let arr = stringofitems.split(",");

        let count = (arr.length / 5 );

        console.log('count = ' + count);
        console.log('arr = ' + arr.length);

        for(x = 1; x < arr.length; x = x + 5){

            if (arr[x] === name){
        
                arr.splice(x-1,5);
                let newstring = arr.join();
            
                localStorage.setItem("stringitem",newstring);
            }

        }

    }

}


function updateprice(x,operation,name){              //updates the total price and stores in localstorage(long memory)


    x = x.replace('$','');
    
   

    if(operation === 'add'){

        if(localStorage.getItem("currentprice") === null){

            localStorage.setItem("currentprice",x); 
            document.getElementById('newprice').innerHTML = '$' + x;
            

        }else{
        
            let temp = localStorage.getItem("currentprice");

            temp = parseFloat(temp) + parseFloat(x);
            temp = temp.toFixed(2);

            localStorage.setItem("currentprice",temp);
            document.getElementById('newprice').innerHTML = '$' + temp;

        }

    }
    if(operation === 'sub'){

        
        
        if(localStorage.getItem("currentprice") === null){

            localStorage.setItem("currentprice",0.00); 
            document.getElementById('newprice').innerHTML = '$0.00';
           

        }else{

            let temp = localStorage.getItem("currentprice");   // get the total of the cart

            let stringofitems = localStorage.getItem("stringitem"); //locate the item to remove and how many qty are in cart.

            let arr = stringofitems.split(","); //define array

            let count = (arr.length / 5 );

            let qty; 

            let amount;

          

            for(x = 1; x < arr.length; x = x + 5){

                if (arr[x] === name){
                    qty = arr[x-1];
                    amount = arr[x+1]
                }  
            }  
              
          
            amount = amount.replace('$','');

            temp = parseFloat(temp) - (parseFloat(amount) * parseInt(qty));  //not yet
            temp = temp.toFixed(2);
            temp = temp.replace('-','');

            if( temp <= 0 ){

                localStorage.setItem("currentprice",0.00); 

            }else{

                localStorage.setItem("currentprice",temp);

            }

            document.getElementById('newprice').innerHTML = '$' + temp;

        }

    }

}




    function additem(name, cost, code){                         //adds the product to the receipt frame

        //delete if it exist-------

        name  = name.replace(/\s+/g, "-");

        const myDiv = document.querySelector('.basketshow');
        const myName = myDiv.querySelector('#a' + name);
        const myValue = myDiv.querySelector('#a' + name + 1);

        let qty;
        let code1;

        
        if(myValue !== null){
            const codeinner = myValue.innerHTML;

            qty = parseInt(codeinner) + parseInt(1);
            code1 = 'a' + qty + ',' + code;

        }else{

        qty = 1;
        code1 = 'a' + qty + ',' + code;

        }

        if (myName !== null){
            myName.parentElement.remove();
        }
       
        //-------------------------

        var new_tr = document.createElement("tr");      //new table row
        new_tr.classList.add('regrow');
       
        var new_td0 = document.createElement('td');     //td with id to hold qty
        new_td0.classList.add('regbody');
        new_td0.classList.add('recqtydiv');
        new_td0.setAttribute('id', 'a' + name + 1);


        var new_td1 = document.createElement('td');     //td with id to hold name
        new_td1.classList.add('regbody');
        new_td1.classList.add('recnamediv');
        new_td1.setAttribute('id', 'a' + name);

        var new_td2 = document.createElement('td');     //td to hold cost
        new_td2.classList.add('regbody');
        new_td2.classList.add('regr');
        new_td2.classList.add('reccostdiv');

        var new_td3 = document.createElement('td');     //td to hold delete button
        new_td3.classList.add('regbody');

        var new_p = document.createElement('p');        //p to be the delete button
        new_p.classList.add('regdel');

        var new_input = document.createElement('input');    //hidden input to hold the information for the form submission
        new_input.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
        new_input.setAttribute("name",code);
        new_input.setAttribute("value",code1);
        
        new_td0.innerHTML = qty;
        new_td1.innerHTML = name;
        new_td2.innerHTML = cost;
        new_p.innerHTML = 'Del';
       
        new_td3.onclick = function() {
            updateprice(cost,'sub',name);
            updatestorage(name,cost,code,'sub');
            this.parentElement.remove(this);
        }
        new_td3.appendChild(new_p);
        new_tr.appendChild(new_td0);
        new_tr.appendChild(new_td1);
        new_tr.appendChild(new_input);
        new_tr.appendChild(new_td2);
        new_tr.appendChild(new_td3);

        $("#recbody").prepend($(new_tr).fadeIn('slow'));

        updateprice(cost,'add',name);
        updatestorage(name,cost,code,'add');
       
    }

   

       

           
          

window.onload = function() {
    
    let stringofitems = localStorage.getItem("stringitem");
    let price = localStorage.getItem("currentprice");
       

    if(stringofitems !== null){
       
        if(price === '0' || price === ''){
           
            document.getElementById('newprice').innerHTML = '$0.00';

        }else{
           
            let arr = stringofitems.split(","); //define array

            let count = (arr.length / 5 );

            let qty;

            for(x = 1; x < arr.length; x = x + 5){

                qty = arr[x-1];
                names = arr[x];
                cost = arr[x+1];
                code = arr[x+2];


                code1 = 'a' + qty + ',' + code;

                const myDiv = document.querySelector('.basketshow');

                var new_tr = document.createElement("tr");      //new table row
                new_tr.classList.add('regrow');
            
                var new_td0 = document.createElement('td');     //td with id to hold qty
                new_td0.classList.add('regbody');
                new_td0.classList.add('recqtydiv');
                new_td0.setAttribute('id', 'a' + names + 1);


                var new_td1 = document.createElement('td');     //td with id to hold name
                new_td1.classList.add('regbody');
                new_td1.classList.add('recnamediv');
                new_td1.setAttribute('id', 'a' + names);

                var new_td2 = document.createElement('td');     //td to hold cost
                new_td2.classList.add('regbody');
                new_td2.classList.add('regr');
                new_td2.classList.add('reccostdiv');

                var new_td3 = document.createElement('td');     //td to hold delete button
                new_td3.classList.add('regbody');

                var new_p = document.createElement('p');        //p to be the delete button
                new_p.classList.add('regdel');

                var new_input = document.createElement('input');    //hidden input to hold the information for the form submission
                new_input.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
                new_input.setAttribute("name",code);
                new_input.setAttribute("value",code1);

                new_td0.innerHTML = qty;
                new_td1.innerHTML = names;
                new_td2.innerHTML = cost;
                new_p.innerHTML = 'Del';

                new_td3.onclick = function() {
                    updateprice(cost,'sub',names);
                    updatestorage(names,cost,code,'sub');
                    this.parentElement.remove(this);

                }
                new_td3.appendChild(new_p);
                new_tr.appendChild(new_td0);
                new_tr.appendChild(new_td1);
                new_tr.appendChild(new_input);
                new_tr.appendChild(new_td2);
                new_tr.appendChild(new_td3);

                //document.getElementById("recbody").appendChild(new_tr);
                $("#recbody").prepend($(new_tr).fadeIn('slow'));

                //updateprice(cost,'add',code);
                //updatestorage(name,cost,code,'add');
               
            }
            document.getElementById('newprice').innerHTML = '$' + price;
        }
    }
};

\\\
```

Comment: I think you'd find it a whole lot easier to use JavaScript objects instead of all this string manipulation, and use `JSON.stringify()` and `JSON.parse()` when moving data in and out of LocalStorage.

Comment: Also: don't post your whole project here. Just post the code relevant to the problem. See [mcve]